# How to get count greater than and less than average values group by name

Tags: mysql

I have a data set with name and their transaction ,how to get average and count of transactions grater than that average and less than that average..

```
Name    Transaction
John    12
John    34
John    45
John    66
John    32
chris   26
chris   54
chris   56
chris   99
chris   13
chris   4
kim     22
kim     34
kim     7
kim     11
kim     34
```

O/P will be

```
Name      Avg     Count_greater_than_Avg    Count_Less_than_Avg
John      37.8          2                           3
chris     42            3                           3
kim       21.6          3                           2
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This basically first add a column `Your_Avg` using a correlated query, and then wrap it with another select to select the count of the occurrences of times smaller then avg and times larger.

```
SELECT tt.name,tt.Your_Avg,
       count(CASE WHEN tt.Your_Avg > tt.Transaction then 1 end) as Greater_Then_Avg,
       count(CASE WHEN tt.Your_Avg > tt.Transaction then 1 end) as Smaller_Then_Avg
FROM(
    SELECT t.name,
           (SELECT avg(s.transaction) FROM YourTable s WHERE s.name = t.name) as Your_Avg,
           t.transaction
    FROM YourTable) tt
GROUP BY tt.name
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.Name, t2.Aver,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Transaction < Aver THEN 1 END) Count_Less_than_Avg,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Transaction > Aver THEN 1 END) Count_greater_than_Avg
FROM mytable AS t1
JOIN (
  SELECT Name, AVG(Transaction * 1.0) AS Aver
  FROM mytable
  GROUP BY Name
) AS t2 ON t1.Name = t2.Name
GROUP By Name
```

You need a derived table in order to calculate the average value per `Name`. You can then `JOIN` the original table to this derived table and use *conditional aggregation* in order to calculate *less than*, *greater than* number of transactions.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4c962/1)